# Inserting a map item into DynamoDb

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table which is indexed by player accounts, and each player account has an empty map called "games." Whenever a new game is created, I'd like to insert a new item into that map for the new game, with some starting values. However this Javascript code below gives me an error:

```js
            let newGame = {
                "live": { "BOOL": true },
                "result": { "S": "in_progress" }
            };

            let params = {
                TableName: "games_roster",
                Key: { "account_id" : playerAccount },
                UpdateExpression: "SET games.#game_id = :new_game",
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                    "#game_id": {"S": gameId}
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":new_game": {"M": newGame}
                }
            };

            await dynamoClient.send(new UpdateItemCommand(params));
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Object.AttributeValue.visit (models_0.js?31ed:996:1)
    at serializeAws_json1_0AttributeValue (Aws_json1_0.js?1450:4056:1)
    at eval (Aws_json1_0.js?1450:4484:1)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at serializeAws_json1_0Key (Aws_json1_0.js?1450:4478:1)
    at serializeAws_json1_0UpdateItemInput (Aws_json1_0.js?1450:5112:1)
    at eval (Aws_json1_0.js?1450:520:1)
    at step (tslib.es6.js?9ab4:102:1)
    at Object.eval [as next] (tslib.es6.js?9ab4:83:1)
    at eval (tslib.es6.js?9ab4:76:1)
```

I've verified that none of the variables are undefined by logging out the params object, so where would I be getting an TypeError?

Owing to @fedanov's answer, this is the correct format:

```
            let newGame = {
                live: { BOOL: true },
                result: { S: "in_progress" }
            };

            let params = {
                TableName: "games_roster",
                Key: { "account_id" : { S: playerAccount } },
                UpdateExpression: "SET games.#game_id = :new_game",
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                    "#game_id": gameId
                },
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":new_game": { M: newGame }
                }
            };

            await dynamoClient.send(new UpdateItemCommand(params));
```

Comment: The OP's title says you are using the "document client". The `DynamoDBDocumentClient` from the v3 `@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb` package?

Comment: @fedonev I think that's correct, specifically ```@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb``` Is that the preferred method for interacting with DDB?

Comment: The "document client" is an alternative client that accepts/returns native JS types rather than DynamoDB JSON. It's in the v3 [@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.html) package.  I removed the reference to it in the title because you are using the standard client.  It's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the wrong types to [UpdateItemCommandInput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/interfaces/updateitemcommandinput.html).  The `Key` parameter expects DynamoDB JSON values, `ExpressionAttributeNames` string values:

```js
Key: { account_id: { S: playerAccount} },
ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#game_id" : gameId }
```

Comment: What about the map for the game? I am still getting the error after fixing the key and expression attribute name.

Comment: Ah, I figured out the right format. I'll update the OP.